# Alamofire post request getting **Invalid value around line 1, column 0.**

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, alamofire

I am trying to hit alamofire post request but, Getting Request failed with error responseSerializationFailed ( reason: **Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed ( error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})**). Please help me to figure out the issue. Thanks.

below is my Api handler method

```
func apiPostRequest1(parameters:[String:String], url:String,  completionHandler: @escaping (Any?) -> Swift.Void) {
    

    var headers = HTTPHeaders(parameters)
    headers.add(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    
    session.request(url,
               method: .post,
               parameters: parameters,
               encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,
               headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            completionHandler(JSON)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error \(error)")
            completionHandler(response.response?.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `print` the received data. Most likely it's not JSON. And – unrelated – consider that `responseJSON` is deprecated in favor of `responseDecodable`

Comment: @vadian response is getting in JSON format on post man. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Don't trust Postman. As I said `print` what you got.

Comment: @vadian i printed response is below **Optional("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\nSize of a request header field exceeds server limit.</p>\n</body></html>\n")** what did i miss

Comment: It's HTML indicating a Bad Request server error, as I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is working when i removed headers from request.

```
func apiPostRequest1(parameters:[String:String], url:String,  completionHandler: @escaping (Any?) -> Swift.Void) {
    
    session.request(url,
               method: .post,
               parameters: parameters,
               encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            completionHandler(JSON)
        case .failure(let error):
            let responseData = String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(responseData ?? "Error in encoding response data")
            print("Request failed with error \(error)")
            completionHandler(response.response?.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with passing the password parameter.
I was passing the encoded password
**requestDict["password"] = (parameters?["password"] as? String)?.encodeToBase64()**
I checked with the backend team and I avoided that and passed the same text password
**requestDict["password"] = (parameters?["password"]**
make sure you are passing the correct parameters and correct URL as per API requirements.